# Erro: O identificador de várias partes não pôde ser associado

Tags: sql-server, join

Estou tentando executar o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT * FROM pendencia, cliente
LEFT JOIN servico ON pendencia.id_pendencia = servico.id_pendencia
LEFT JOIN cidade  ON cliente.id_cidade = cidade.id_cidade
WHERE cliente.id_cliente = pendencia.id_cliente AND servico.ativo = 1
```

E o SQL Server me retorna o seguinte erro:

**Mensagem 4104, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 2
O identificador de várias partes "pendencia.id_pendencia" não pôde ser associado.**

Não sei onde estou errando, alguém sabe me dizer o que tem de errado?

Segue esquema do banco:

[image: Esquema do banco]

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas talvez tenha a ver com você misturar `JOIN`s com `,` na hora de listar as tabelas. Tente colocar a tabela `cliente` como `INNER JOIN` (e parte do `WHERE` iria para o `ON` desse JOIN).

Answer (score 2):

Corrija seu `JOIN` ou use com vírgula ou use com o `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM pendencia a
JOIN cliente b ON a.id_cliente = b.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN servico c ON a.id_pendencia = c.id_pendencia
LEFT JOIN cidade d ON a.id_cidade = d.id_cidade
```

Assim acredito ser melhor e não acusar o erro, o problema está na sua sintaxe.